# RF transmitter with external 8-12v power not working properly

Tags: power, rf

So I have this pair of transmitter and receiver
[image]

RPI is powered by USB from laptop
Transmitter is connected to Attiny85 being interfaced from RPI at 3v3
Receiver is connected to Arduino at 5v

If I have transmitter VCC connected to RPI 5v, data pin to Attiny85 running at 3.3v and all of them having same ground - all works fine, but obviously range is not great.
At this point same ground connects: transmitter, Attiny, RPI.

So I've tried using external power supply for transmitter.

I have power brick with DC output running at 12v
[image]
DC output positive goes to VCC, negative to common ground.
At this point same ground connects: transmitter, Attiny, RPI, power brick.
This doesn't work at all, receive nothing.

I have YwRobot breadboard power, which is broken and now supplies 8v on 5v pins
[image]

I've connected same power brick DC output to YwRobot DC in, positive 5v from board (actually pushing 8v) goes to VCC, negative from board goes to common ground.
At this point same ground connects: transmitter, Attiny, RPI, YwRobot.
This setup transmits data some times, still worse results than connecting VCC to RPI 5v.

Am I missing something? Does external power supply has to be something specific? I've thought as long as grounds are connected any power supply can be used on transmitter.

**Update:**
This 433MHz transmitter with PCB integrated antenna from my thermostat (powered by 2xAA) has no problem penetrating 3 walls and floor in my house. Sorry for my ignorance, but I need to achieve similar form factor and performance. 2.4GHz modules also require a lot of pins limiting what else can be done with Attiny85.
[image]

**Update:**
Attiny is using [manchester](https://github.com/mchr3k/arduino-libs-manchester) and software serial (part of Arduino IDE) on [attiny core](https://github.com/damellis/attiny).
RPI is using [serial](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/), not sure which version, installed using `sudo apt-get install python-serial`

Comment: Nice powerbank, where did you buy it? It runs about 200USD on amazon. Does it take standard 18650 LiPo cells?

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01DLRGY8A it's enclosed unit

Comment: That’s an impressive 433 module, I can’t seem to find it on google however. Link?

Comment: Have you got an SDR dongle to verify that data is being transmitted at all? Can you attach an oscilloscope probe to the datapin going to the 433 module? Have you tried receiving on an arduino 168/328p? Have you verified that the attiny has enough RAM free? Are all the pins okay - what does ‘really pushing 8V’ mean? 8V to attiny?

Comment: Data is being transmitted - I connect transmitter and receiver wire directly as they all share same ground. There are no issues with receiver, because by changing power supply to transmitter, receiver starts to receive data. Basically 5v power of GPIO to VCC (transmitter) all good, 8v power of breakout power module to VCC spotty receiving, 12v power of power brick to VCC nothing received. All of them share GND so I'am just switching power cable while module is constant transmitting.

Comment: I have those 5V/3V boards, they are unsafe. Firstly, the FET will fail open if you pull too much current, secondly they output very noisy signal. Try a 7805/lm317 (and/or lm1117), esp. for radio stuff.

Comment: OK - I'm not concerned about 5V/3V board, but when I use my power brick directly to transmitter, is that the same thing? Power coming to transmitter is being too noisy? I'll look into voltage regulator, but could using voltage booster (5v -> 12v) be a better idea for transmitter VCC? I will have 5v power supply for RPI, so I would take v5 from power supply directly to voltage booster and from voltage booster to VCC.

Comment: If it uses a step-down, it will have a certain frequency for 5V signal - you can use a 7805 with 0.22 and 0.1uF caps to smoothe this out. Be careful, it will surge to 6-7V for a millisecond if fed from 12V. You can look at this: http://www.electronicdesign.com/power/select-right-varistors-overvoltage-circuit-protection . Usually my arduinos don’t die from this momentary surge:) P.S.: Google best cap values for your design; .22 and .1uF are not mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Those 433MHz modules are tricky. I got the best results with 3V3 on the receiver, and 5V on transmitter. You should add an external antenna.

While it would be prudent to remove the little loop antenna, you don’t need to. I got an okay signal at 25 meters with line-of-sight. Metal, or brick will block the signal even at a meter or so - there’s no penetration. Consider a 2.4GHz module for high penetration at low range, or a LoRa module for high range (up to 10km).

A 433MHz antenna I’ve used with good results (can be cut for any frequency really)
[image: Ant1]

Use the same material for both antenna and radials - copper is good - and optionally stiffen the radials with bicycle spokes on the *inside* ... make sure there is no electrical contact between the radials and the spokes; tape or heatshrink tube. I found coax cable to suck hard for this application, so I recommend using shielded headphone wire or something similar... just connect the shield to 0V/GND.

As for your breakout power module, I’ve had the same issue. Those modules are dangerous, avoid them. Use 7805 and LM1117 instead. Or just one 5V source (your powerbank?) and a TO-92 LM317 set to 3V3 output (max 100mA). Tiny 3V step-down converters like this can supply 800mA.
https://m.banggood.com/5V-To-3_3V-DC-DC-Step-Down-Power-Supply-Buck-Module-AMS1117-800MA-p-933674.html
( you can find them a lot cheaper )

Comment: My project is home automation setup, so 433MHz is preferred as 2.4GHz is so crowded and adding another 4 low-powered devices wouldn't improve situation. I've ordered these https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/172936544379 to try out, but thing is, my current 433MHz still should work with very small antenna within the house. I've dissembled my current thermostat and it has similar 433MHz transmitter with tiny coiled antenna and have no problem connecting to boiler across whole house. I already have external antennas from multi-thread cable, but will try to get some solid copper wire for testing.

Comment: @goodevil You will not penetrate even a finger with these modules... the 2.4GHz modules have ways to mitigate band saturation - else look at 860/900MHz.

Comment: I've update my question - as similar size device is able to achieve what I need

Comment: With my current setup I am ALREADY penetrating wall and floor, adding another wall makes receiving spotty and taking receiver even further, prevents it from receiving anything.
I've update my question - as similar size device is able to achieve what I need, I assume I just missing something in my setup. nRF24L01 would leave my Attiny with no available pins, or in best case with 2 pins, which is my plan B if I can't replicate performance of current thermostat.

Comment: @goodevil What library are you using?

Comment: @goodevil ... on the pi and attiny85?

Comment: updated main question with list of libraries